# Visual Studio 2015 does not find existing Web Apps on Azure Cloud during Web Deploy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service

On my **Azure** account I have several **Web Apps**.

I'm trying to deploy my **ASP.NET MVC** project from **Visual Studio 2015** using **Publish**. But it doesn't find any existing Web Apps on my Azure account. I logged in in Visual Studio. Credentials are correct. But list of existing Web Apps in VS is empty:

[image]

---

I select **Microsoft Azure Web Apps**:

Then it's loading some time and finally the list of existing Web Apps is empty. 
[image]

---

I thought that it's my specific project that doesn't work. Then I created new ASP MVC Web Application (template). Still, the list is empty.

My IDE: **MS Visual Studio Professional 2015-U3**

---

What might be a reason that VS cannot find existing Web Apps on my Azure cloud account? I tried to reenter my credentials, logout and login. Nothing.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have updated my **Microsoft Azure SDK** from version **2.7** to a newer (**2.9.6**) and problem resolved. Now it works. The list of existing resource groups and web apps is correct. 
[image]

---

*As @Marnee mentioned:*

> In Visual Studio go to `Tools` >> `Extensions and Updates`. Click on
>   `Updates` in the left-hand pane. You should see the Azure SDK with a
>   `Update` button. Follow that.

Comment: [Adding more information] Go here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/
and download SDK for VS 2015

Comment: In Visual Studio go to Tools >> Extensions and Updates.  Click on Updates in the left-hand pane. You should see the Azure SDK with a Update button.  Follow that.